# use textview to display message when json response is null

Tags: android, json, textview

In my JSON response I am **get nothing in value** and at that I **want to print message using textview** I am trying but its not showing nothing,can any one help?the response is looks like this

```
{"name":"Patel Monali","age":24,"location":"","mother_tounge":"","occupation":"","income":"","height":"","cast":"","marital_status":"","religion":"","gotra":"","manglik":"","rashi":"","education":"","eating":"","drink":"","smoke":"","about_me":"","profile_pic":"Imaege","user_status":"Accept","interest_id":1288}
```

and here is the code:

```
 try {  
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    String user_name = jsonObj.getString(USER_NAME);
    String user_age = jsonObj.getString(USER_AGE);
...............


    final TextView uname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.namedetail);
    final TextView fdetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstdetail);
..............

    uname.setText(user_name);
    fdetail.setText(user_age+" years");

    androidAQuery.id(ucover).image(user_pro, true, true);
}catch (JSONException e)
{   
   e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: Its not allowing to put my code here

Comment: How you updated the TextView ? Post your LogCat also

Comment: It shows error when i try to add code here

Comment: i edit my question ccheck now

Comment: its may be because you have already added to much code.

Comment: what message do you want to print on the textview?

Comment: in all null fields i need to "not willing to specify"

Comment: Try this : uname.setText(user_name!=null && user_name.trim().length()>0?user_name:"not willing to specify");

Comment: `if(user_name.equals("")){uname.setText("not willing to specify");} else {uname.setText(user_name);}`

Comment: @HareshChhelana where can i add this ?

Comment: Replace with this : uname.setText(user_name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly here is what you need

```
    if(user_name==null)
      {
       uname.setText("not willing to specify");
     }
    else
     {
     uname.setText(user_name);

      }
```

If you need something more please update your question or tell me in comments.
.
Hope it help

Comment: i know the logic but where can i add this ?

Comment: its working to me thanks zoya i vote up and accept,,you also vote up question

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is check if the received string is null.
for example:

```
 String user_occupation = jsonObj.getString(USER_OCCU);
if(user_occupation.length==0){
user_occupation="not willing to specify";//set your message here
}
                 OR


String user_occupation = jsonObj.getString(USER_OCCU);
if(user_occupation==null){
user_occupation="not willing to specify";//set your message here
}
```